# Displaying content of single post

Tags: posts

How I can display content for a single post?
My code:

```
if (is_single()){
    get_header();
    get_sidebar('left-article');
    render_article();
    get_footer();
}
```

In `render_article` I call `single_post_title()` to get title of post.
However I don't know how to get time and contents of the post as I can't find any function like `single_post_content()` or `single_post_time()`.

Comment: You need to study [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) first

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Create a file named single.php. This will automatically get all you single posts. For more information about WordPress' template hierarchy, [read the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)
2. Inside single.php, run the default loop and get header.php, sidebar.php and footer.php

   ```
   <?php get_header(); ?>
   <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>

   <?php endwhile; ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
   <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
   <?php get_footer(); ?>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

you can use below function to get content of Wordpress post

```
     <?php echo get_the_content(); ?>
```

and you can use below function to get title

```
    <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
```

to get date you can use this function

```
    <?php echo echo get_the_date(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function my_category_templates($single_template) {
    global $post;

    if ( in_category( 'Offers' )) {
        $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/single-offer.php';
    }

    // Copy the above for your other categories

    return $single_template;
}

add_filter( "single_template", "my_category_templates" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use get_post() to get specofic post

```
get_post()
```

Example :

```
<?php $postData = get_post( $id, $output, $filter ); 

echo "<pre>";
print_r($postData);
?>
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/

https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/query-or-show-a-specific-post-in-wordpress-php-code-example-44

Answer (score 0):

This is an ancient question, but none of the answers here tell the proper way of doing this, so I want to provide a better alternative.  No need to use a bunch of random global functions or rely upon some nebulous global state created by this awful "Loop" thing.

If you are displaying the contents of a single post, then you need to create a file called "single.php" inside your theme's directory.  (https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)  This will be the template for your posts.

single.php

```
<?php

    namespace mytheme; // You should designate a namespace for your theme so that it does not conflict with WordPress, its parent theme, or any plugins you may have installed.

    defined('ABSPATH') || exit; // Exit if the file is being executed directly instead of by WordPress.

    $post = get_queried_object(); // This object contains all the data about the post that you need.  You do not need to use a bunch of random global functions or the Loop to get the post data.  If you want to see the contents of this object, then use var_dump when debugging.

    if (!$post) {
        $wp_query->set_404();
        status_header(404);
        http_response_code(404);
        exit;
    }

    get_header();
?>

<main>
    <h1><?php echo strip_tags($post->post_title); ?></h1>
    <?php if ($post->post_content) { ?>
        <div>
            <?php echo do_shortcode(apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content)); ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</main>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```